# how to save changes after reordering data in edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am completely new to swift developing. I want to implement a UI table view which it could shows a list of my items in array like the image below

[image: how my table views]

It works fine but when I move items places and then I touch done button, after restart the app, every changes that I have made, resets to its default. I searched a lot and I found that I should save it on user defaults. I read lots of articles but still I do not know what should I do with codes, I appreciate if some one could edit my codes the way I need
(reordering changes could save on device and not refreshing each time I open the app)

here is my codes in viewController

```
   //  ViewController.swift
  //  Created by Sebastian Hette on 28.02.2017.

import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
//I defined user defaults here

 struct Constants {

    static let myKey = "myKey"
}
//I defined my static key here

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    defaults.stringArray(forKey: Constants.myKey)
    //I retrieve user defaults here 


    cell?.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}

//Allows reordering of cells
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let item = array[sourceIndexPath.row]
    array.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    array.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}


@IBAction func edit(_ sender: Any)
{
    myTableView.isEditing = !myTableView.isEditing

    switch myTableView.isEditing {
    case true:
        editButton.title = "done"
    case false:
        editButton.title = "edit"
    }



    defaults.set(array, forKey: Constants.myKey)
    //I saved my user defaults here 
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


   }
```

Comment: if you don't save updated array in user defaults  when you re-launch app next time the "array" reinitialised they way of defined in viewController. you have to get array from user defaults.

Comment: @AshokPolu thank you very very much. Im completely new to swift and I put lots of effort on it to find what I should  do exactly but I could not find. I will appreciate if you  can update with exact codes for saving and reading array in  user default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need a UserDefaults object:

`let defaults = UserDefaults.standard`

To save:

```
defaults.set(0, forKey: "myNumber")
defaults.set("hello", forKey: "myString")
defaults.set(["apple", "banana", "grape"], forKey: "myArray")
```

To retrieve:

```
defaults.integer(forKey: "myNumber")
defaults.string(forKey: "myString")
defaults.stringArray(forKey: "myArray") // you can also save any type of array by using defaults.array
```

You can save multiple types, including numbers (int, double, float, etc), strings, boolean, object, and arrays. I recommend storing the keys in a separate Constants or similar file, because typos in the key values could cause this not to work and you'll be banging your head on the wall trying to figure out a more complex reason as to why your app isn't working. An example:

`static let myKey = "myKey"`

and to use would be

`Constants.myKey`

By using UserDefaults your app will save the order of your data even after it closes. Instead of declaring an array in your ViewController, initialize your array in viewDidLoad.

**EDIT:**

You're almost there. I'm not seeing a `viewDidLoad` method, which I believe you'll need. Here's a little sample I whipped up:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var array = [String]() // declaring a String array
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard // where the data will be stored

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // this sets the array equal to the last saved array, or the default one if one has not been saved
        array = defaults.stringArray(forKey: myKey) ?? ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    }
}
```

Every time you are ready to save your new ordered array call `defaults.set(array, forKey: myKey)`. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, take out the line where you retrieve user defaults, you won't need it now that you're retrieving it on `viewDidLoad` and setting it equal to your array variable.

And if it were me, I would save the user defaults as the last line in the `moveRowAt` method.

Comment: thank you ver very much again. I updated my code the way I got from your guide but it still not saving the changes user made to list. I define my key like this in the first codes of view controller under the code for defining array, and then saving by setting it in `@IBAction func edit(_ sender: Any)` load and retrieve in `cellForRowAt`. I really appreciate your help very very much. thank you

Comment: I tested again with defining my key in its own codes for defaults like this `defaults.stringArray(forKey: "mykey")` and `defaults.set(array, forKey: "myKey")` but stil not working. Please please help if possible.

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh I've posted an edit to my answer detailing this process

Comment: wow works fine, I do not know how to thank you. Appreciate very very much for your helpful guide. thank you again.